# Remove default › between breadcrumbs in panels breadcrumbs

Tags: panels, breadcrumbs

Is it possible to remove the › between the breadcrumbs in the panels breadcrumbs module?  I tried modifying the part of the .module file shown below (which I know is bad practice, but I just  wanted to try it out) but that did not work.

```
// Finally, render the breadcrumb
foreach ($breadcrumbs_info as $crumb) {
if (isset($crumb['href']) && $crumb['href'] == '<none>') {
  $crumb['localized_options'] += array('attributes' => array(), 'html' => TRUE);
  $breadcrumbs[] = '<span ' . drupal_attributes($crumb['localized_options']['attributes']) . '>' . ($crumb['localized_options']['html'] ? $crumb['title'] : check_plain($crumb['title'])) . '</span>';
}
else {
  $breadcrumbs[] = l($crumb['title'], $crumb['href'], $crumb['localized_options']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your own custom theme (or a sub-theme you can edit), you can override [theme_breadcrumb()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7). Actually I'm not sure this is completely supported by panels_breadcrumbs but I assume it is.

```
THEMENAME_breadcrumb() {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' CUSTOM SEPARATOR ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Alternatively, there are other breadcrumb-customizing modules that allow to specify a custom separator between the breadcrumb items.

Comment: You are right, it was the theme which was controlling what was being displayed as the separator.